# Save multiple GUIdata sets to listbox and then load them again in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox, matlab-guide

I have built a calculation software in MATLAB GUIDE. What I want to do is to fill out all my calculation data in different edit fields and some dropdowns and when I press calculate a "listbox" should be populated with the text "Calculation 1".

If I then change some data in some of the input fields and press calculate again I want to populate the listbox with "Calculation 2" beneath "Calculation 1" etc...

But then I would want to be able to highligt "calculation 1" again in the listbox and press a "load input parameters" button to populate all the edit input fields with the data that was used when "calculation 1" was calculated.

I have looked all over the place for this but can't find anything.

//Robin

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code which is very basic but performs what you are looking for. There are a lot of tweaks possible but I'll let you play around with them. I put explanations as comments. You can copy past into Matlab and change the GUI as you like.

```
function CalculatorGUI

% Dummy GUI to calculate A*B + C...
clc
clear 
close all

global hTestResult hEditA hEditB hEditC CalculationList CalculationStrings

% Set up controls
CalculationList = nan(10,3); % Create array in which we store the parameters. 1st column is A, 2nd is B and 3rd is C.
CalculationStrings = cell(10,1);

ScreenSize = get(0,'ScreenSize');

hFig = figure('Visible','off','Position',[ScreenSize(3)/2,ScreenSize(4)/2,450,285]);

hCalculateButton = uicontrol('Style','Pushbutton','Position',[350,150,80,30],'String','Calculate!','Callback',@CalculateCallback);

hTitle = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[100,250,100,25],'String','Calculate (A * B) + C');

hTextA = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[125,220,70,25],'String','A');
hEditA = uicontrol('Style','Edit','Position',[125,200,70,25],'String','1');

hTextB = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[200,220,70,25],'String','B');
hEditB = uicontrol('Style','Edit','Position',[200,200,70,25],'String','2');

hTextC = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[275,220,70,25],'String','C');
hEditC = uicontrol('Style','Edit','Position',[275,200,70,25],'String','3');

hResultHeader = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[350,220,70,25],'String','Result');
hTestResult = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[350,200,70,25],'String','');


hTextCalcu = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[100,140,100,50],'String','Calculations');
hListCalcu = uicontrol('Style','Listbox','String','','Position',[100,120,200,50],'max',10,...
    'min',1,'Callback',@ListBox_Callback);

set(hFig,'Visible','on')
%======================================================================
%======================================================================

% Callback of the pushbutton
    function CalculateCallback(~,~)

        % Get the values in the edit boxes. There is no ckechup to make
        % sure the user entered a correct value...
        A = str2double(get(hEditA,'String'));
        B = str2double(get(hEditB,'String'));
        C = str2double(get(hEditC,'String'));

        Calculation = A*B+C;

        % Display the result.
        set(hTestResult,'String',sprintf('The result is %0.2f',Calculation));        

        % Find how many calculations have been performed and append the
        % parameters to the current list

       [x,~] = find(~isnan(CalculationList));
       CurrentCalc = numel(unique(x)); % Get number of rows which are NOT NaNs.

       CurrentValues = [A B C];


       CalculationList(CurrentCalc+1,:) = CurrentValues;
       CurrentString = sprintf('A = %0.2f B = %0.2f C = %0.2f',A,B,C);

      % Assign the parameters to the cell array.
       CalculationStrings(CurrentCalc+1) = {CurrentString};
       set(hListCalcu,'String',CalculationStrings)

    end

% Listbox callback: When the selection changes, the corresponding
% parameters in the edit boxes change.

    function ListBox_Callback(~,~)

        SelectedCalc = get(hListCalcu,'Value');

        CalculationList(SelectedCalc,1)
        CalculationList(SelectedCalc,2)
        CalculationList(SelectedCalc,3)

        set(hEditA,'String',CalculationList(SelectedCalc,1));
        set(hEditB,'String',CalculationList(SelectedCalc,2));
        set(hEditC,'String',CalculationList(SelectedCalc,3));
    end

end
```

The actual interface looks like this:

[image]

Of course you can make it much more complex, but this should help you get started and understand how the different callbacks work together. Have fun!